Is This Approach Feasible?
Given a finite set of input-output pairs, is it possible to restore the function using Fourier transform-based interpolation, and then approximate the function with a polynomial that is easier to compute using the Weierstrass approximation theorem?

You can also interpolate using polynomials and Chebyshev nodes.

If all you have is a discrete set of $n$ points, then you can always find a polynomial of degree at most $n$ that fits those points exactly via polynomial interpolation.
If you want to fit a polynomial of lower degree and minimise some kind of error measurement on the fit, then you can probably apply some kind of polynomial regression.
In both of these cases, applying a Fourier transform is going to do very little except add an extra step, since you're just doing two sets of interpolation and you're not adding any extra information by doing so.
